# Same action method for multiple buttons---UI Navigation Controller - 87445

Tags: objective-c, xcode

HI I am new to XCODE and trying to make a view based application which uses navigation controllers. In one of my views am trying to attach same action method for different buttons. Am using tag property for UIButtons.

The code is

```
@interface firstview : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

    }

    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

    -(IBAction)push:(UIButton *)sender;

    @end



    #import "firstview.h"
    #import "secondview.h"


    @implementation firstview

    @synthesize button1;
    @synthesize button2;

    -(IBAction)push:(UIButton *)sender{

    button1.tag = 1;
    button2.tag = 2;


    if(sender.tag = button1.tag){
    secondview *v2 = [[secondview alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:Nil];
    v2.title =@"first button";
    v2.l1.text = @"BUTTON1";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
    [v2 release];
    }
    else if(sender.tag = button2.tag){
    secondview *v2 = [[secondview alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:Nil];
    v2.title =@"Select";
    v2.l1.text = @"BUTTON2";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];
    [v2 release];
    }

    }

    @end
```

I want that when a particular button is pressed, the title of the view should change and also the text of the label. But implementing the above code is giving me the view for first button, no matter which button I press. I will appreciate if someone can tell me where am going wrong.

As per the suggestions, i changed the equality sign. But the label is still not showing the text.

Comment: Did you make sure that every IBOutlet is connected?

Comment: Yup they are. The title is changing but the text of the label is not changing

Comment: Quick question: where did `l1` come from?

Comment: My secondview is having a label and button. l1 refers to the IBOutlet of that label

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `sender.tag = button1.tag`, not `sender.tag == button1.tag`. You need to use two equal signs to check for equality.

What's happening is that you're setting `sender.tag` to the value of `button1.tag`. After that code runs, the program evaluates `if (sender.tag)`. Since `sender.tag` will always equal `1`, `if(sender.tag)` == `if(1)` == `YES`.

Comment: Yup...the title of the view is changing but the text of my label is not changing. I had connected the outlet with controller

Comment: The IBOutlet is connected to the controller